# How to change the local datetime format in react Input

Tags: json, spring, reactjs

I'm trying to add a value of local datetime , the format in backend  is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. I'm trying to change the format in react to get it but it's always `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`. How can I change it ?
 Here's the code

```
 @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") private LocalDateTime start_date;
```

the input code

```
 <Input type="datetime-local" value={this.state.end_date} onChange = {this.handleEndDateChange} />
```

and the output format is  "2019-07-30T08:00"

Comment: Try this - https://momentjs.com/

Comment: thank you i tried already but doesn't help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the format in `handleEndDateChange` function.

```
handleEndDateChange = (event) => {
  dateString = event.target.value.replace('T', ' ');
}
```